# Objective -C AES: 128 Bit, CBC, IV Encryption?

Tags: objective-c, encryption, aes, shopify

I'm building an iOS client for generating a token for Shopify's Multipass: http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/multipass-login

Our nodeJS code is working fine (using the library https://github.com/beaucoo/multipassify), so I’m using that as a reference. What I found out was the the length of the `cipherText` generated in `NodeJS` (208 bytes) is significantly shorter than the one for `Objective-C` (432 bytes). This is the function that performs the AES 128 bit, CBC, IV encryption:

NodeJS (correct)

```
multipassify.prototype.encrypt = function(plaintext) {
    // Use a random IV
    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', this._encryptionKey,iv);

    // Use IV as first block of ciphertext
    var encrypted = iv.toString('binary') + cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'binary') + cipher.final('binary');
    return encrypted;
}
```

Objective C (incorrect?)

```
- (NSData *)encryptCustomerDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)customerDict{
    NSData *customerData    = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:customerDict];

    // Random initialization vector
    NSData *iv = [BBAES randomIV];

    //  AES: 128 bit key length, CBC mode of operation, random IV
    NSData *cipherText = [BBAES encryptedDataFromData:customerData
                                                      IV:iv
                                                     key:self.encryptionKey
                                                 options:BBAESEncryptionOptionsIncludeIV];

    return cipherText;
}
```

`

The NodeJS version passes in a plainText as an argument, and that should be a stringified version of the JSON object `customerDict`. Ideally, the bytes returned by both function should be the same length. I'm using the `BBAES` library for encryption, have no idea how to do this with the `CommonCrypto` library. Am I implementing the objective C function correctly?

Comment: The problem with so many of these libraries is that they do not provide compatibility and do not throughly document the inner workings, that is how the primitives are used and combined. By going with Common Crypto on the iOS/OSX side at least it is clear exactly what is being done.

Answer (score 1):

First I thought that the BBAES library would convert the result to hexadecimals, but that did not seem to be the case (I actually checked the source code).

So the only logical reasoning seems to be that the input is double the length. That could for instance be the case if UTF-16 (or any other multi-byte character encoding) is used for encrypting text.

Furthermore I do see that BBAES prepends the IV to the ciphertext as well. That and possibly some additional padding overhead could make enough difference for the ciphertext to be *over* twice the size compared with NodeJS.

Hint: view the binary input's to your functions *in hexadecimals* to make sure that there are no differences!

Comment: +1 for view the hex! You have to look at the hex to see the problem, if you can't see the problem you can't fix the problem (Paraphrasing Willy Jack).

Comment: @Zaph Where's the +1? You *promised* (sniff) :P

Comment: Oops, sorry, I thought I had clicked!